# Salesforce web2lead form not sending data to salesforce

Tags: php, salesforce

I have this custom web2lead form, but it's not sending any data to salesforce. This was created by someone months ago and I cannot figure out what's wrong.

This is the form processing script, which inlcudes the sleaforce code:

```
<?php

/*error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);*/

session_start();

//print_r($_POST);
//die;

function DoStripSlashes($fieldValue)  { 
 if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) { 
  if (is_array($fieldValue) ) { 
   return array_map('DoStripSlashes', $fieldValue);
  } else { 
   return stripslashes($fieldValue);
  } 
 } else { 
  return $fieldValue;
 } 
}

function FilterCChars($theString) {
 return preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F]/', '', $theString);
}

function CheckEmail($email, $optional) {
 if ( (strlen($email) == 0) && ($optional === kOptional) ) {
  return true;
 } elseif ( eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$", $email) ) {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}

//$ini_array = parse_ini_file("form_values.ini");
//print_r($ini_array);


////////////////////////honeypot check////////////////////////////////////////
if(isset($_POST['userComment']) == true && $_POST['userComment'] != ""){
$_SESSION['prev_value']=$_POST;
header("Location: free-quick-quote-sftest.php?honey=1");
exit();
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



////////////////////////Arithmatic check////////////////////////////////////////
if(isset($_SESSION['arrval']) && isset($_POST['arrval']) && $_SESSION['arrval'] != $_POST['arrval']){
$_SESSION['prev_value']=$_POST;
header("Location: free-quick-quote-sftest.php?arrval=1");
exit();
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


////////////////////////html check////////////////////////////////////////

if(isset($_POST['comments'])) {
$fbk=$_POST['comments'];
$fbk2=strip_tags($fbk);
}

if(isset($_POST['comments']) && $_POST['comments']!=$fbk2){
$_SESSION['prev_value']=$_POST;
header("Location: free-quick-quote-sftest.php?insertion=1");
exit();
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if(isset($_POST['fullname'])) {
$name = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['fullname'] );

$email = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['email'] );
$phone =DoStripSlashes( $_POST['phone'] );
$traveltype = DoStripSlashes($_POST['traveltype']);
$triptype = "";

if(isset($_POST['triptype']) == true) {
$triptype = DoStripSlashes($_POST['triptype']);
}

$departure_date = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['departure_date'] );
$departure_time = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['departure_time'] );
$departure_city_state = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['departure_city_state'] );
$destination_info = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['destination_info'] );
$hours = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['hours'] );
$service_type = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['service_type'] );
$vehicle_type = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['vehicle_type'] );

$heard = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['heard'] );

if(isset($_POST['other_comments']))
$heard_comments = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['other_comments'] );

$comments    = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['comments'] );

if($heard=="Other"){
    $heard=$heard_comments;
}
}


//print_r($_POST);
 $validationFailed = false;
if ( $validationFailed === false ) {

$field_name = array();

    $debug = 1;
    $debugEmail     = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $oid                 = "myoid";
    $prefix             = "00N30000006m";

if(isset($name))
$newname = explode(" ", $name);

    $first_name =(!empty($newname[0])) ? $newname[0] : "unspecified";
    $last_name = (!empty($newname[1])) ? $newname[1] : "unspecified";

if(isset($departure_city_state))
$departure = explode(",", $departure_city_state);

if(!isset($departure[0]))
$departure[0] = "";

if(!isset($departure[1]))
$departure[1] = "";

if(!isset($departure[2]))
$departure[2] = "";

if(isset($destination_info))
$destination = explode(",", $destination_info);

if(!isset($destination[0]))
$destination[0] = "";

if(!isset($destination[1]))
$destination[1] = "";

if(!isset($destination[2]))
$destination[2] = "";

    if(isset( $field_name['debug'])) {
    // Identify the name="field_name as key="value"
    $field_name['debug'] = "1";
    $field_name['oid']                    = $oid;
    $field_name['retURL'] = "http://www.mysite.net";

    //departure city
    $field_name['00N30000006mRon']     = trim($departure[0]);

    //departure state
    $field_name['00N30000006mRpk'] = trim($departure[1]);

    //departure date/time
    $field_name['00N30000006mRpf'] = $departure_date . " " . $departure_time;

    //destination city
    $field_name['00N30000006mRpp'] = trim($destination[0]);

    //destination state
    $field_name['00N30000006mRpu'] = trim($destination[1]);

    //hours
    $field_name['00N30000006mRpz'] = $hours;

    //special requests
    $field_name['00N30000006mRqE'] = $comments;

    //passengers
    $field_name['00N30000006mRde'] = "1";

    //vehicle
    $field_name['00N30000006mRqO'] = $vehicle_type;



    //referral source
    $field_name['00N30000006oJV0']    = $heard;

    //occasion
    $field_name['00N30000006mRq4'] = $service_type;

    $field_name['first_name']            = $first_name;
    $field_name['last_name']            = $last_name;

    $field_name['phone']                    = $phone;
    $field_name['email']                    = $email;
    $field_name['lead_source']            = "Web";
     }



$post_items = array();

    foreach($field_name as $key=>$value){
        $post_items[] = $value."=".$key;
    }


    // $post_string = implode("&",$post_items);
   // $post_string = urlencode($post_string);
    $curl_connection = curl_init("https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8");
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    //curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//$headers = array();
//$headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
//$headers['Content-Length'] = strlen($post_string);
//curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($field_name));
    //curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

    curl_close($curl_connection);


//mail("developncode@gmail.com", "Salesforce", $result);


 # Email to Form Owner

 $emailSubject = FilterCChars("Transportation Quote Request");

  if(isset($name)) {
 $emailBody = 
    "<h1>Transportation Quote Request</h1><br/>"
  . "<strong>Name:</strong> $name<br/>"
  . "<strong>Email:</strong> $email<br/>"
  . "<strong>Phone:</strong> $phone<br/>"
  . "<strong>Travel Type:</strong> $traveltype<br/>"
  . "<strong>Trip Type:</strong> $triptype<br/>"
  . "<strong>Pickup date:</strong> $departure_date<br/>"
  . "<strong>Pickup time:</strong> $departure_time<br/>"
  . "<strong>Pickup city, state, zip:</strong> $departure_city_state<br/>"
  . "<strong>Dropoff city, state, zip:</strong> $destination_info<br/>"
  . "<strong>Requested hours:</strong> $hours<br/>"
  . "<strong>Service type:</strong> $service_type<br/>"
  . "<strong>Vehicle type:</strong> $vehicle_type<br/>"
  . "<strong>How did you hear about us:</strong> $heard<br/>"
  . "<strong>Comments:</strong> $comments<br/>"
  . "<br/><br/>"
  . "www.mysite.com<br/>"
  . "";
  }

  $emailTo="myemail@gmail.com";

  //$emailTo=$ini_array[$service_type];
  if(isset($email)) {
  $emailFrom = FilterCChars("$email");

  $emailHeader = "From: $emailFrom\n"
   . "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
   . "Content-type: text/html\n"
   . "Content-transfer-encoding: 7bit\n";

  mail($emailTo, $emailSubject, $emailBody, $emailHeader);
   //mail("developncode@gmail.com", $emailSubject, $emailBody, $emailHeader);
  //echo "mail: $emailBody <br> $emailTo";

  # Redirect user to success page

    header("Location: http://www.mysite.net/sent.html");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, and a very vague description of the error. Have you done any debugging? Do you know where the error is occuring? In the validation? In the Curl code? When it tries to send the email? Can you try and narrow things down for us?

Comment: I'm not really sure where to start. All I know is that it was sending data and now it's not.

Comment: What do you mean by sending the data? Does it get added to Salesforce with the CURL call? Do you still get the email? Have you checked the error logs on the server to see if there's anything in there? Have there been any upgrades on the server recently?

Comment: Hi @Wolf Cat, there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Come join the community over there! :)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the OrgID got replaced with a demo or test org, or some field has changed which you are binding to from the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$oid                 = "SPECIFY_YOUR_SALESFORCE_INSTANCE_ID";
```

`$prefix             = "00N30000006m";` this is not required

For Sandbox :

```
$curl_connection = curl_init("https://www.test.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8");
```

For Production

```
$curl_connection = curl_init("https://www.login.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8");
```